# How two different react route render using a same component in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 routes

1. Adding a new product
   **/products/new**
2. Edit a product
   **/products/:id**

both routes render on a same component .

issue is this, if current route is editProduct then if i click on 'add new product' route then nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your routes in order so `/products/new` is matched before `/products/:id`

```js
<Route path="/products/new" component={NewProduct} exact />
<Route path="/products/:id" component={Product} exact />
```

In the above snippet `/products/new` will render `NewProduct` component and `/products/anything-other-than-new` will render `Product` component